# why my placeholder not showing up

Tags: html, css, placeholder

i have form in html that can search but my placeholder not show. i have many search but not working for that.
please help me

```css
.search-widget {
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  float: left;
}

.search-widget input {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  height: 35px;
}

.search-widget :hover,
.search-widget :focus {
  border-color: #1293D4;
}

.search-widget button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #1293D4;
  border: 0;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-widget">
  <form action="#">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="search" required>
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i can see it on jsfiddle? It may be about some javascript that changes display of input.

Comment: I can see it fine.

Comment: it also shows in the SO snippet

Comment: You are doing something wrong, i ran this and i get the placeholder

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: in all browser not work

Comment: they was an edit of your code, maybe it corrected the issue .. consider putting back your previous code

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about **search icon** not showing up on place of placeholder then this may help you, here you missed to add external css `fontawesome.css` to your code, Check below snippet for reference which shows placeholder with icon.

```css
.search-widget {
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  float: left;
}

.search-widget input {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  height: 35px;
}

.search-widget :hover,
.search-widget :focus {
  border-color: #1293D4;
}

.search-widget button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #1293D4;
  border: 0;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="search-widget">
  <form action="#">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="search" required>
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </form>
</div>
```